# What is the error: NSDebugDescription=The connection to service with pid 68 named com.apple.pegasus was invalidated from this process

Tags: ios, swift, picture-in-picture

I was trying to Adopting Picture in Picture for video calls followed the link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/adopting_picture_in_picture_for_video_calls
Now when i go to background i receive error on my console:
[Common] -[PGPictureInPictureProxy (0x14d526a60) _updateAutoPIPSettingsAndNotifyRemoteObjectWithReason:] - Acquiring remote object proxy for connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x283c68960> connection to service with pid 68 named com.apple.pegasus failed with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service with pid 68 named com.apple.pegasus was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service with pid 68 named com.apple.pegasus was invalidated from this process.}

What is this error for?
It will be helpful if anyone can help on this.

Comment: The Apple Pegasus service is completely unrelated to the spyware made by NSO: it's the name of the Apple service for Picture-in-Picture support. As long as everything is working, you can completely ignore this warning. Otherwise, file a bug report.

Comment: Thank you for the response, i understand that but i want to know what is this error for because the PIP code not working even i followed the same process mentioned by Apple.